# access multiple instances of an object outside of method

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a class named `Vehicle` and a class named `Car` that inherits from `Vehicle`. I have a form where you can create a car object by filling in some info and clicking a button. This info is inserted into a gridview.

What I want to do is to access a specifik Car object by the ID I created it with.

I created an ID to identify each car object. I want to be able to access a certain object, like the Car object with ID 3.

I have a combo box that I want to fill with all the Car IDs, so that I later on can select a specific car object and clone it, as an example. I use an event that checks for RowsAdded to the `DataGridView`. When a row is added, the `ComboBox` should be added with the `car id`.

The problem I have is that I can not access the object `testCar` in the event that checks for `RowsAdded`. I have tried to declare the object instance outside of the `buttonclick` event to then change that object inside the `buttonclick` event but that does not work. I am thinking that perhaps I need to create an object array where I insert every different car.

heres my code:

```
class Car : Vehicle
{
    string carBrand = "";
    private static int carID { get; set; }
    public int iD { get; set; }
    public string CarBrand { get; set; }
    public Color CarColor { get; set; }
    public Car()
    {
        carID = 0;
        CarBrand = "Volvo";
        CarColor = Color.Black;
    }
    public Car(string vehicleName, int vehicleYear, string carBrand, Color carColor)
    {
        this.iD = GetNextCarID();
        this.VehicleName = vehicleName;
        this.VehicleYear = vehicleYear;
        this.CarBrand = carBrand;
        this.CarColor = carColor;
    }
    static Car() 
    {
        carID = 0;

    }
    protected int GetNextCarID()
    {
        return ++carID;
    }


    public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string inputModell = txtModell.Text;
        int inputCarYear = Int16.Parse(txtCarYear.Text);
        string inputBrand = cmbCarBrands.SelectedItem.ToString();
        Color inputColor = Color.Black;
        if (colorDialog1.Color != Color.Black)
        {
            inputColor = colorDialog1.Color;
        }
        Car testCar = new Car(inputModell, inputCarYear, inputBrand, inputColor);
        int id = testCar.iD;

        if (txtModell.Text != string.Empty && txtCarYear.Text != string.Empty)
        {                
            dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 6;
            dataGridView1.Columns[0].Name = "ID";
            dataGridView1.Columns[1].Name = "Modell";
            dataGridView1.Columns[2].Name = "Årtal";
            dataGridView1.Columns[3].Name = "Märke";
            dataGridView1.Columns[4].Name = "Färg";
            dataGridView1.Columns[5].Name = "Orginal/Klon";
            int currRow = dataGridView1.Rows.Add(testCar.iD, testCar.VehicleName, testCar.VehicleYear, testCar.CarBrand, "", "Orginal");
            DataGridViewCellStyle cellStyle = new DataGridViewCellStyle();
            cellStyle.BackColor = testCar.CarColor;
            dataGridView1.Rows[currRow].Cells[4].Style = cellStyle; 
        }
    }

    private void dataGridView1_RowsAdded(object sender, DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e)
    {
        groupBox2.Enabled = true;
        cmbCarID.Items.Add(testCar.iD);
    }
```

Comment: Why do you have button click and datagrid mutations in a `Car` class?  Is that really how your code is organized, or is it an error in posting here?  Separate the UI from the business logic.  The `Car` class should know nothing of concepts like buttons.

Comment: Sorry about that. The event buttonclick is not inside the car class, its in a different class file altogether. the buttonclick is in the "main" class file if you can call it that. Sorry, total n00b ;9)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `Dictionary` is just made for a task such as this.

On your form create a `Dictionary<int, Car>` as a field:

```
private Dictionary<int, Car> carLookup = new Dictionary<int, Car>();
```

Then in your button click event add each new car to it:

```
carLookup[newCar.iD] = newCar;
```

You can now easily look up a car by ID using the dictionary:

```
public Car GetCar(int id)
{
    return carLookup[id];
}
```

Comment: sorry for being a total n00b but where do I put the GetCar method? I get an error about inconsistent accessiblity. Inconsistent accessibility: return type '_4stepbystep.Car' is less accessible than method '_4stepbystep.v3start.GetCar(int)' i put both the dictionary and the getcar method directly after the form class

Comment: @user1987473 The class `Car` should be `public`.  Put that before the definition of the type.

Comment: did not take long for next question hehe. How do i loop through all existing instances of the car object. I tried a while i != null GetCar(i), i++ but an integer can never be null.

Comment: actually I think I solved it. foreach (KeyValuePair<int, Car> car in carLookup)

Comment: @Xerion You can do that, although personally I perfer to use this pattern: `foreach(int key in carLookup.Keys){Car value = carLookup[key];}` when `foreach`-ing a Dictionary.  They both work just fine though.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, It sounds like you want a collection of cars, something resembling this

```
class Car : Vehicle
{
    ...

    List<Car> CarList;
    public Car()
    {
        CarList = new List<Car>  // do this in each constructor
        ...
    }

    ...


    public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Car car = new Car();

        ...

        CarList.Add(car);
    }
}
```

on a side note, I don't know if the `Car` class is the most appropriate place for `button_1Click` to be.

Comment: hmm ok. Lets say I have created a list that holds 5 different cars. How can I access a specifik car in the list?

Comment: If you have link, you can do something like CarList.Where(cl => cl.iD = myID).First().

Comment: @user1987473 you can also just iterate through the list

Comment: @SamIam Lists are not designed for searching.  You should use a data structure that's specifically designed for efficient searching, such as a Dictionary.

Comment: @Servy Lists can perform better for small datasets, but dictionary keeps the same performance even when the number of items increases to very high values. But generally it's a good rule to use dictionary when searching yes.

Comment: @FRoZeN A `List` will only be faster when the number of elements is one, two or three, for most of my tests.  it's usually right around four elements that they are equal, and anything past that and a Dictionary will be better, if not a lot better.  There is never any point in time in which a List will be dramatically faster.

Comment: @Servy Agreed, above 3 is a good rule of thumb to switch to dictionary according to the performance tests i've seen. I was merely supplying an opposing view to make people think about it :) thinking is the first step to learning. :P  on the subject: http://www.dotnetperls.com/dictionary-time

Comment: @FRoZeN But the point is that if there is only one or two items in the collection then you just don't care, the performance is *always* O(1) when `n < 4`.

Comment: @Servy the performance is always O(1) when n < C where C is any constant.

Answer (score 0):

no need to collections! 
you can access the last car which has been added to the datagridview by accessing the last row of the datagridview

```
private void dataGridView1_RowsAdded(object sender, DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e)
{
    int lastRowIndex = dataGridView1.Rows.Count-1;
    int carId = int.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[lastRowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
    groupBox2.Enabled = true;
    cmbCarID.Items.Add(carId);
}
```

Comment: I am more used to databases. in sql I'd do something like Select * from cars where carID=3. I'd take the values from that specifik car and do stuff with it, like update it or clone it. thats basicly what I want to do with this car object. Is there no easy and fast way to access each object that has been created? I probably need to do something completly different hehe

Comment: whenever a new row is added, it's id is inserted into the combobox. later he can use these ids and retrieve other information from datagridview

Comment: it gives and error when I try this. Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Windows.forms.DataGridViewRow'. This is to this part: dataGridView1.Rows[lastRowIndex][0]

Comment: sorry! try this: int.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[lastRowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString()); I also edited it in my answer.

Comment: new error: NullReferenceException was unhandled. Object reference not set to an instance of an object.